# Do test strava accounts exist?

Tags: api, strava

I'm building a website which allows users to connect with Strava and sync their 'run' activities but to test things I could really do with some test strava accounts which have lots of activities on them! My own Strava account is pretty sparsly populated sadly!

Does anything like this exist?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know if test accounts exist but you can create a fake PRIVATE profile (https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216919377-Private-Activities-and-Private-Uploads; no segment, no leaderboard, etc.) and populating it with gpx of activities of other athletes using https://mapstogpx.com/strava/